# Failed to resolve: androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0

Tags: android

I want to use the RequestPermission contract, documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin) says that I need to add the androidx.activity library and need to use its version 1.2.0 and above to make it work.

When I keep library version as 1.1.0 it works, but it does not contain RequestPermission.

When I update to 1.2.0, I see the error **Failed to resolve: androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0**

Answer (score 1):

The version `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0` [**doesn't** exist](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.activity#androidx.activity:activity-ktx).

You can use the latest stable version:

```
androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0
```

or the latest alpha version:

```
androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha07
```